# How much did the Re:Zero anime adapt the light novel and did it skip any content?

Tags: re-zero

I want to watch the anime, but first I need to read the light novel. Thus, I wanted to know how much the anime adapted the light novel and whether or not the anime skipped any content?

Answer (score 2):

They skipped a particular loop in the anime when Subaru went to the mansion to warn about the incoming witch cultist attack.

In this loop,

> Subaru tries to convince the mansion residence to evacuate. When he tried to convince Beatrice to move out, he failed and learned a slight clue about who Beatrice really is. Then he was killed by the witch cultist later on and restart again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember the anime went to part way through volume 10, maybe even less.
In terms of the adaption, from Volume 1 (only one I've read so far) it adapted about 80% of the content.

> Think he's died a few more times in the LN.

Answer (score 0):

They haven't really skipped anything. As of October 19, they've adapted up to the start of the 13th Light Novel.